# I need help building this tic-tac-toe game using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, web, tic-tac-toe

I need to create a tic-tac-toe game using PHP. Here is my initial code, however, clicking a tile in the table only refreshes the page and it does not register my input in the board. How can I make this code work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        /* Styling for the game board */
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: auto;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        td:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // Initialize the game board
        $board = array(
            array("", "", ""),
            array("", "", ""),
            array("", "", "")
        );

        // Check if a player has won the game
        function checkWin($board, $player) {
            // Check for horizontal win
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                if ($board[$i][0] == $player && $board[$i][1] == $player && $board[$i][2] == $player) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // Check for vertical win
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                if ($board[0][$i] == $player && $board[1][$i] == $player && $board[2][$i] == $player) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // Check for diagonal win
            if ($board[0][0] == $player && $board[1][1] == $player && $board[2][2] == $player) {
                return true;
            }
            if ($board[0][2] == $player && $board[1][1] == $player && $board[2][0] == $player) {
                return true;
            }

            // No win found
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the game is a tie
        function checkTie($board) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
                    if ($board[$i][$j] == "") {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Start the game
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            // Get the player's move
            $row = $_POST["row"];
            $col = $_POST["col"];

            // Update the game board
            $board[$row][$col] = "X";

            // Check if the player won the game
            if (checkWin($board, "X")) {
                echo "<h1>You win!</h1>";
                exit();
            }

            // Check if the game is a tie
            if (checkTie($board)) {
                echo "<h1>Tie game!</h1>";
                exit();
            }

            // Computer's move
            do {
                $row = rand(0, 2);
                $col = rand(0, 2);
            } while ($board[$row][$col] != "");
            $board[$row][$col] = "O";

            // Check if the computer won the game
            if (checkWin($board, "O")) {
                echo "<h1>You lose!</h1>";
                exit();
            }

            // Check if the game is a tie
            if (checkTie($board)) {
                echo "<h1>Tie game!</h1>";
                exit();
            }
        }
    ?>

    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

    <table>
        <?php
            // Display the game board
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
                    echo "<td onclick=\"location.href='?row=$i&col=$j'\">";
                    echo $board[$i][$j];
                    echo "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

i EXPECTED THE PROGRAM TO REGISTER MY INPUT BY PLACING AN 'X' in the table but it does not show anything upon clicking.

Comment: I see where the page reload is passing the latest human move, but I don't see where you are preserving the board.  Do you want to use a `$_SESSION` variable to make the board data persistent per game?

Comment: Alternatively, you might refactor your design to [always submit the whole board](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33974603/2943403) -- this is a work around for not using a session array.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `POST` request method and then for the values in the global `$_POST` variable, however when you redirect the user to the location with the JavaScript you have written, it's not actually posting anything -- you're simply appending data to the URL, i.e. using a query string.

To get the data from the URL, you need to use the global `$_GET` variable. Now, since the initial page load is also a `GET` request, your `if` condition can't simply check if it's a `GET` request method, but you might check if `row` and `col` are set, which would not be the case on initial page load.

For example:

```php
if (isset($_GET['row'], $_GET['col'])) {
    // Get the player's move
    $row = $_GET["row"];
    $col = $_GET["col"];
    // ...
}
```

That said, you will run into another problem: your data doesn't persist. The moment you make another move, the previous moves will be lost.

You have a few options to solve this. Either look into [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) or [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php), and then read and write your board there, or you could keep appending things to the URL (chaining the values) by using an array:

```php
echo "<td onclick=\"location.href='?moves[]=1,1&moves[]=0,0'\">";
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to add the computer's move to the URL as well.

Comment: `isset()` can be a single call. https://3v4l.org/ALi3d

Comment: @mickmackusa This is honestly insane. I've been reading and writing PHP code for years, and I've never seen or used `isset()` with more than one variable in a single call, and it never occurred to me to read its docs. You're absolutely right-- thank you!